# Restriction of a line bundle to a submanifold

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $N^{n}$ be a complex submanifold to $M^{m}$, where $n$ and $m$ are their dimensions. Let $V_{M}$ be the holomorphic cotangent bundle of $M$. Then we can consider the determinant line bundle $K_{M} = \wedge^{m} V_{M}$ of $M$, and $K_{N}$ for $N$. We know that $K_{N} = K_{M|N} \otimes det(N_{Y|X})$, where $N_{Y|X}$ is given by  the exact sequence $0 \to V_{M} \to V_{M|Y} \to N_{M|N} \to 0$.

<s>{Why would not it be the case that $K_{M|N} = K_{N}$? We can choose coordinates so that $N \to M$ looks like $(z_1, \ldots, z_n) \to (z_1, \ldots, z_n, 0, \ldots, 0)$. Then the pullback of $dz_1 \wedge \ldots dz_m$ onto $N$ is just $dz_1 \wedge \ldots \wedge dz_n$. Where does this extra component in the tensor product come from?</s>

As the comment pointed out the above is not correct. Then my question I guess is how to think of this restriction concretely. For instance what is the restriction of $dz_1 \wedge \ldots \wedge dz_{n}$ to $N$?

Comment: You need to go back to basics. Isn't the pullback of an $m$-form always an $m$-form?

Comment: Along $N$, you're going to have to contract the $m$-form with an $(m-n)$-vector normal to $N$, and that gives you an $n$-form on $N$. That's pretty much what adjunction says. You might try it explicitly for the case where $N$ is a hypersurface.